# Using fwrite to include quotation marks for character fields in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am having an issue outputting character fields in a data table with there quotation marks. I am using the fwrite function with the data.table package.

```
for (i in 1:length(mpfdf)){ 
  fwrite(x[[i]], file = paste0('../',x[[i]]), row.names = F, col.names = T)
 }
```

**My Expected Output:**

```
Header1,Header2,Header3

1,"abcd",5
```

**My Actual Output:**

```
 Header1,Header2,Header3

 1,abcd,5

 5,bbbb,6
```

I have also tried to use the quote parameter as follows:

```
for (i in 1:length(mpfdf)) {
  fwrite(mpfdf[[i]], file = paste0('../',mpfs[[i]]), row.names = F, col.names = T, quote ="auto")
  }
```

This gives me the same actual output as above.

I have also tried the following:

```
for (i in 1:length(mpfdf)) {
  fwrite(mpfdf[[i]], file = paste0('../',mpfs[[i]]), row.names = F, col.names = T, quote =T)
  }
```

However this also makes the headers in the output contain "".

e.g.

```
   "Header1","Header2","Header3"

   1,"abcd",5

   5,"bbbb",6
```

I am sure there is a way around this but I am still relatively new to using R for data manipulation. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the quotes to the column and then `fwrite()` with `quote = FALSE` to prevent it from adding additional quotes.

```
DT[, Header2 := paste0('\"', Header2, '\"')]
fwrite(DT, "test.csv", quote = FALSE)
```

Output

```
Header1,Header2,Header3
1,"abcd",5
5,"bbbb",6
```

Reproducible data:

```
DT <- fread(
 "Header1,Header2,Header3
 1,abcd,5
 5,bbbb,6"
)
```